# How to develop role based workflow in SharePoint Server?

Tags: workflow, infopath

How to develop role based workflow with InfoPath form in SharePoint Server 2010?

There are three roles:

user1 - this user creates request form

user2 - this user verifies and Approve/Reject form if user Approves mail will sent to user3.

user3

How to develop this type of workflow?

Please explain sharepoint designer workflow actions?

Answer (score 0):

As there are variations to this scenarios which could be foreseen, i would go for the simplest - use the Workflow initiation/association forms to allow the initiator to configure these 3 roles by selecting appropriate users or groups at workflow start. What do you decide to do afterwards is your choice of course, but having these stored as variables via the initiation parameters would enable you to use them across the whole life-cycle of the workflow.

Make sure the variables are of type People/Group when declaring them.